# Incorrect response from .get_or_create function in Django

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models, django-queryset

I have been trying to understand why the .get_or_create function I'm using isn't working. It's supposed to find the object in the DB with matching parameters and create a new one if none are found. When running this, it always says that there are not matching objects and the tuple return True every time hence always creating a new object (a duplicate).

This causes the Except statement to run every time as well.

Here is my function:

```
for desktop in desktops:
        try:
          clean_location = serialized_location_information(desktop)
          clean_machine = serialize_machine_information(desktop)
          location_name, location_created = Location.objects.get_or_create(
            latitude=clean_location["latitude"],
            longitude=clean_location["longitude"],
            provider=clean_machine["provider"],
            defaults={
              "country": clean_location["country"],
              "state": clean_location["state"],
              "city": clean_location["city"],
              "street_address": clean_location["street_address"],
              "postal_code": clean_location["postal_code"],
              "name": clean_location["name"],
              "status": clean_location["status"],
            }
          )
          if location_created:
            logger.info(f"New Location was created successfully")
        except Exception as ex:
          logger.error(f"Could not get or create location: {ex}")
          location = None
          pass
```

Here is my model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['latitude','longitude','provider']

    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=10, choices=LocationStatus.CHOICES)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default= '')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

Comment: I think you got a typo,  `if l_created:` try changing it to `if location_created:`

Comment: What value you are passing in the `clean_machine["provider"]` is it an object or string ?

Comment: The value is a string

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to get or create the `provider` object first and then lookup for Location object like below :-

```
for desktop in desktops:
        try:
          clean_location = serialized_location_information(desktop)
          clean_machine = serialize_machine_information(desktop)
          provider, _ = Provide.objects.get_or_create(provider_name = clean_machine["provider"])
          location_name, location_created = Location.objects.get_or_create(
            latitude=clean_location["latitude"],
            longitude=clean_location["longitude"],
            provider=provider,
            defaults={
              "country": clean_location["country"],
              "state": clean_location["state"],
              "city": clean_location["city"],
               ...
               ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work because there are multiple objects that have the same provider